# jQuery Masonry not animating on resize in IE8

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, jquery-masonry

I'm building a website with a responsive design [website](http://www.trackmyeps.com/responsive/). But the masonry animation that should rearrange the blocks isn't working properly in IE8. 
It seems like it only runs after another resize is done.

So it should animate after the CSS of the media query for smaller screens starts being used.

But it animates after this CSS is being used and the screen is resized again.

How do i fix this?